# Where are all of the pedestals?

Tags: a-hat-in-time

Purple time rifts are activated by placing relics on pedestals. So far, I have found three pedestals and completed a set of relics on each of them:

- The two pedestals in the main room of the ship
- The pedestal in the gallery

I've looked everywhere I can think of in my ship and can't find a fourth pedestal. Where is it located? Are there any more pedestals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing only one pedestal. The four pedestals, including the ones I mentioned in my question, are:

- Two in the main room
- One in the gallery
- In the Alpine Skyway room, there is a door with a picture of a laboratory beaker on it. Just inside this door is a strange purple wall. Use the Dweller mask to get past it and find the final pedestal.